# Getting abstract superclass mapped by a View using Hibernate returns Invalid column name

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

The situation is as following. Say I've got a Kid, and I want to get his Parent. The abstract Parent is situated in a View. The Parent can either be a Mother or a Father. The Mother is also defined in a View.

```
@Entity
public class Kid extends DomainObject {
    private IParent theParent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Parent.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TheParentId")
    public IParent getTheParent() {
        return theParent;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTheParent(IParent theParent) {
        this.theParent = theParent;
    }
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "Parent")
public abstract class Parent {

}

@Entity
public class Mother extends Parent {

}
```

So, using Hibernate, I try to retrieve the Mother-object by calling getTheParent() on Kid:

```
from Kid hobj left join  fetch  hobj.theParent pa
```

This works fine in the database. But when running this via Hibernate, it returns SQL exception: Invalid column name(UNKNOWN)

There are a few pointers which can be the cause. In the old database, Mother and Father were Table's instead of Views. My guess is that Hibernate understood the link because of foreign keys. Changing the Parent from Table to View broke the application. But searching around points out that Hibernate treats View's and Table's equally (to some extent). Why does getting the exact query being used by Hibernate work when entered directly, but not when using Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be in the select-clause of the query. When adding multiple objects to the select column (running deeper with more tables then Kid, Mother and Father), Hibernate would get confused. When I only used the Kid-object (and fill up items using Kid.getX().getY().getZ()... ), Hibernate had no problem fetching everything.

Seems to be a bug in Hibernate.